# What is causing WLSTException: oracle.wtst.exception.WeblogicRequestTimeoutException during Weblogic server shutdown using WLST?

Tags: oracle, exception, weblogic, wlst, request-timed-out

This Exception occurred at Sat May 27 15:37:29 BST 2023.
weblogic.rmi.extensions.RequestTimeoutException: RJVM response from 'weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl@4daa0139 - JVMID: '-7049265161388177056S:10.22.76.41:[-1,-1,7002,-1,-1,-1,-1]:inetAddress=gbcroappat0021.qbe.eo/10.22.76.41:base_domain:edq_server1' connect time: 'Fri May 26 12:26:47 BST 2023'' for 'shutdown(IZZ)' timed out after: 2000ms.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
File "/u01/app/oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain/shutdown-edq_server1.py", line 4, in ?
File "", line 1372, in shutdown
File "", line 553, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing shutdown : Error shutting down the server : RJVM response from 'weblogic.rjvm.RJVMImpl@4daa0139 - JVMID: '-7049265161388177056S:10.22.76.41:[-1,-1,7002,-1,-1,-1,-1]:inetAddress=gbcroappat0021.qbe.eo/10.22.76.41:base_domain:edq_server1' connect time: 'Fri May 26 12:26:47 BST 2023'' for 'shutdown(IZZ)' timed out after: 2000ms.
Use dumpStack() to view the full stacktrace :

I was restarting the services and I got this error can anyone please say what to do?